# difference between c and c++ char pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants, string-literals

In C this works totally fine:

```
char* Test = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
Test = "Hey";
```

Meanwhile in Cpp it throws me this error:

```
char* Test = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
Test = "Hey";
```

> a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"

What is the difference between these two and why is a pointer in Cpp alsways a const and cant be modified later?

Comment: Both snippets don't do what you think they do. Both allocated chunks of memory are lost. __Both character literals are constant__, C just doesn't treat them as `const`. It would, however, just crash if you try to modify it.

Comment: @tkausl I think you could make that an answer.

Comment: Do you want `Test` to point to a block of memory you allocated or do you want it to point to a string literal? It can't do both at the same time.

Comment: Also, a string literal is not a pointer.   It is represented as an array.   The only reason your compiler gives a warning mentioning pointers is that `Test = "Hey"` involves an implicit conversion to a pointer, so assigns `Test` to be equal to the address of the first character in the literal (which has value `'H'`).   It does NOT mean an array is a pointer - because they are different tings.

Answer (score 9):

First of all the both code snippets (if to add the qualifier `const` to the pointer in the second code snippet) produce a memory leak because at first  memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `Test` and then the pointer was reassigned with the address of the first character of a string literal. As a result the address of the allocated memory is ;lost.

In C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays.

From the C++ 17 Standard (5.13.5 String literals)

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
> to as narrow string literals. **A narrow string literal has type
> “array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as
> defined below, and has static storage duration (6.7)

So in C++ you have to write

```
const char *Test = "Hey";
```

Nevertheless though in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays you may not change string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

As for your code snippets then you should at least write

In C

```
char* Test = malloc( 4 * sizeof( cha));
strcpy( Test, "Hey" );

//...

free( Test );
```

on C++

```
char* Test = new char[4];
std::strcpy( Test, "Hey" );

//...

delete [] Test;
```

Comment: Might want to add a comment that, in C++, it is usually considered preferable to avoid usage of `new`/`delete` and `std::strcpy()` and, instead, use `std::string` to represent a string.